# MVC Validation - Non required fields being forced to fill in before submitting form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have the following fields in my view that are being required to fill in before submitting my form.

VIEW:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BusinessPhone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control boldgray", @placeholder = "Business Phone" } })
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MobilePhone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control boldgray", @placeholder = "Mobile/Alternative" } })
</div>
```

MODEL:

```
[DisplayName("Home Phone")]
[Required]
public int HomePhone { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Business Phone")]
public int BusinessPhone { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Mobile Phone")]
```

These fields are marked to "Allow Null" in my database and do not have the [Required] data annotation in my model.  Why are they being required before submitting my form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe try using nullable ints for the phone numbers?

eg:

```
 [DisplayName("Business Phone")]
        public int? BusinessPhone { get; set; }
```

Comment: Awesome!  That worked great. Unfortunately I don't have 15 points yet to give you a point :(

Comment: you could mark it as the correct answer - i think you might even get some points?